# Java operator ' !=' cannot be applied to 'double' 'null'

Tags: java, null, double

I'm new to java and I'm building a hotel reservation system. I'm trying to write a method to check if a room is free, but i keep getting this error message "Java operator ' !=' cannot be applied to 'double' 'null'"
Here's the code:

```
double price;
public double isFree() {

    return this.price != null && this.price.equals(0.0);
}
```

Comment: `public double isFree` means that the method should return a double.  Th expression that you have written evaluates to a boolean i.e. (true/false).

Comment: primitives (int, float, double etc) do not have methods and can not be `null`

Comment: Just change type of price from `double` to `Double`;

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a *reference* - a pointer to an object. Like an address in an address book. In java, all objects are stored as an address. That's because it's *a lot* simpler to give you an address on a piece of paper, than it is to copy an entire house on a piece of paper.

`null` is a special value: An address where everybody knows - there's nothing there.

`double` is a primitive. **Not an object**. It doesn't have an address at all. To transfer primitives around, they're just... transferred. That's why *all* primitives are small, and fixed size.

Given that they aren't an address, they cannot be `null`.

When you  create a field, they start as 0.0. There is no way to differentiate '0' from 'not set yet'.

`.` is the dereference operator: It basically means "look up this address then walk over to it". Hence, you can't do that on doubles. `price.anything` doesn't work. `price == 0.0` would.

I'm not exactly sure if `price` is a good way to convey whether a room is free, maybe you want to comp one. Still, if you insist:

```
public boolean isFree() {
  return this.price == 0.0;
}
```

Note: This returns a `boolean` - of course it should. "is it free" is a question you answer with a `boolean` value, not a `double` value.